# Parametric prolate epicycloid modelling and integration

Tags: integration, analysis, functions, parametric

I was trying to model an epicycloid for my math assignment but none of the parametric equations I found ended up helping me model it on desmos.

One of the more prominent equations I found on the internet was the following:

$$ x=(a+b)\cos \theta -R\cos \theta \left(\frac{a+b}{5}\theta\right) $$
and
$$ y=(a+b)\sin \theta -R\sin\theta \left(\frac{a+b}{5}\theta\right) $$

However, when I input these functions and substitute $a=16m, b = 2m, R = 8m$

it should give me something like this
[Prolate epicycloid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4EZH.png).

My math assignment revolves around modeling a fountain to trace that shape from a bird's eye view perspective. I must find out the velocity which the fountain must trace at to clearly see the shape while it is in motion.

However, since the prolate epicycloid isn't a function, it cannot be integrated to find the velocity, so if there are some other methods that can be used please let me know, regardless of how complex they are.

If modeling the following shape can be done another way to make it easier, then please let me know as well.

Comment: I think you may have incorrectly transcribed the "prominent equation"; see the plot [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=parametric+plot+%7B18+Cos%5Bt%5D+-+144%2F5+t+Cos%5Bt%5D%2C+18+Sin%5Bt%5D+-+144%2F5+t+Sin%5Bt%5D%7D%2C+t+from+-6pi+to+6pi). Compare to [this curve](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=parametric+plot+%7B18+Cos%5Bt%5D+-+8+Cos%5B%2818+t%29%2F5%5D%2C+18+Sin%5Bt%5D+-+8+Sin%5B%2818+t%29%2F5%5D%7D%2C+t+from+-5pi+to+5pi) which seems more in line with what you wanted. Also known as an [epitrochoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epitrochoid).

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "finding out the velocity which the fountain must trace at to clearly see the shape while it is in motion"? And "integrate to find the velocity"? What exactly do $x,y$ represent?

Comment: the prominent equation was what i found online in some academic research papers. By what you have told me, i believe they may be incorrect.

Comment: when i look at the fountain from a bird's eye view (directly above) i can see the shape of the prolate epicycloid without the water on. when the water is turned on, then i need to see the water trace the shape of the epicycloid. so the fountain will move around the epicycloid like a go kart travelling around a track. the water will shoot straight up. however, if the velocity of the water jet is not fast enough, then it won't won;t trace the shape well enough to see it clearly. so if i have a function for the epicycloid, then i can integrate to find the velocity and again to find acceleration